# Unmarshal json to float. Why is float64 required?

Tags: json, go, floating-point, unmarshalling

I've noticed some strange behavior with the way go unmarshals json floats. Some numbers, but not all, refuse to unmarshal correctly. Fixing this is as easy as using a float64 instead of a float32 in the destination variable, but for the life of me I can't find a good reason why this is the case.

Here is code that demonstrates the problem:

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    . "github.com/shopspring/decimal"
)

func main() {
    bytes, _ := json.Marshal(369.1368) // not every number is broken, but this one is
    fmt.Println("bytes", string(bytes))

    var f32 float32
    json.Unmarshal(bytes, &f32)
    fmt.Printf("f32 %f\n", f32) // adds an extra 0.00001 to the number

    var d Decimal
    json.Unmarshal(bytes, &d)
    fmt.Printf("d %s\n", d) // 3rd party packages work

    // naw, you can just float64
    var f64 float64
    json.Unmarshal(bytes, &f64)
    fmt.Printf("f64 %f\n", f64) // float64 works
}
```

A float64 isn't required to accurately represent my example number, so why is required here?

Go playground link: https://play.golang.org/p/tHkonQtZoCt

Comment: I haven't looked closely, but I'd say the cause is roundoff error due to the nature of floating-point numbers: the number whose decimal representation is `369.1368` may not be exactly representable by a `float32`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken

Comment: https://floating-point-gui.de/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your assertion is wrong: `369.1368` cannot be represented exactly by *either* `float32` *or* `float64`.

The closest `float32` value is (approximately) `369.136810302734375`, whcih rounds to `369.13681` which is where your extra digit comes from.  The closest `float64` value is (approximately) `369.13679999999999382`, which rounds more nicely for your purposes.

(Of course, if you round either of these to just four digits after the decimal point, you get the number you expected.)

A `Decimal` representation is exact: there is no rounding error.

JSON transmits and receives floating point values expressed in decimal, but actual *implementations*, in various languages, then *encode* those numbers in different ways.  Depending on what sort of entity you're talking to via JSON, encoding and decoding via `Decimal` could preserve the number exactly as you'd like, but be aware that programs written in, say, C++ or Python might decode your number to a different floating-point precision and introduce various rounding errors.

[This Go Playground example](https://play.golang.org/p/lK74nNlxhMv) uses the newly-added `%x` format, and shows you how the numbers are stored internally:

> as float32 = 369.13681030273437500 (float32), which is really 12095875p-15 or 0x1.712306p+08

and:

> as float64 = 369.13679999999999382 (float64), which is really 6493923261440380p-44 or 0x1.712305532617cp+08

That is, the number 369.*whatever* is internally represented in binary.  It's between 2<sup>8</sup> = 256 and 2<sup>9</sup> = 512.  In binary, it is 1 256, no 128, 1 64, 1 32, 1 16, no 8, no 4, no 2, and 1 1: 1.01110001*something* x 2<sup>8</sup>.  The `%b` format expresses this one way and the `%x` format another, with `%x` starting with `1.72` (1 . 0111 0010).

See [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/1256452) (as jub0bs linked in a comment) for more.

Comment: So I guess the real answer is, the first line of the main function is using a float64 at compile time? My tests indicate that this would be true.

Comment: On further examination, forcing the variable to a float32 still allows for the json marshaler to correctly format the output: [https://play.golang.org/p/IRr2dxY4KvV](https://play.golang.org/p/IRr2dxY4KvV). My best guess at this time is that a) a lot of my constants are indeed poor choices for float32, and b) the json marshaler only writes 4 digits of precision without [explicitly forcing the formatting](https://play.golang.org/p/leGylce2aE2).

Comment: You can see the json unmarshaller source code [here](https://golang.org/src/encoding/json/decode.go?#L903) (scan down to the `default` case that handles number, and then the `reflect.Float32, reflect.Float64` case). You can see the default marshaller [here](https://golang.org/src/encoding/json/encode.go?#L545). These point directly to source line numbers that might change over time, though.

Comment: See also these two closed Golang issues: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/6384 https://github.com/golang/go/issues/14135. I suggest you read through the second one closely and follow some of the links to committee discussions on formatting numbers in JSON.